# Write graphql schema which is equivalent pojo/entity/ class

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, graphql

My entity class in my application is as follows.

```
@Entity
public class User{
@Id
@Column(name = "userId")
Long userId;

@Column(name = "name")

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy="user", cascade = cascadeType.ALL)
@JsonIgnoreProperties("user")
String name;
List<PhoneNumber> phoneNumbers;

//setters ans getters
}

@Entity
Public class PhoneNumber{
@Id
@Column
Long phoneid;

String PhoneNo;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "userId")
@JsonIgnoreProperties("phoneNumbers")
User user;
//setters and getters
}
```

In the above entity classes. I have 2 scenarios:

1. one to many relationship user had many phone numbers (List of phone numbers)
2. many to one relationship many phone numbers belongs to one user

I need to fetch the data both ways. How can i write user.graphqls and phonenumber.graphqls files to represent the these entities and graphqlseolvers also. I am unable to get the data.I got following exception

> Type java.util.Set cannot be mapped to a GraphQL type! Since GraphQL-Java deals with erased types at runtime, only non-Parameterized classes can represent a GraphQL type.

This allows for reverse-lookup by java class in interfaces and union types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In GraphQL you need to define entity/document with type.
Please find below type definitions for your question:

```
type User{
 userId :Long
 phoneNumbers :[PhoneNumber]
}

type PhoneNumber{
 phoneid :  Long
 PhoneNo  : String
 user: User
}
```